# Proyecto DAO con VB6

Tags: vb6

Tengo un proyecto pequeño en VB6 que trabaja con una base de datos ACCDB y utiliza el Microsoft Office 16.0 Access Database Engine para realizar consultas.

Y desde hace un tiempo, por una actualización de windows creo, da errores incoherentes con cosas que normalmente funcionan bien. Por ejemplo, 'la variable de tipo object o la variable de bloque with no está establecida'. Reinstalas el Access Database Engine y todo vuelve a funcionar normalmente. Hasta la próxima actualización de windows.

A alguien le pasa algo parecido?